# Procedure for moving a NodeJS project to TypeScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

It seems that just installing it and then changing file extensions to `.ts` is not enough to effectively move to TypeScript with a NodeJS project. I get about 400 errors that seem to stem mostly from module resolution issues (but not only).

There are a couple of guides covering this topic, but they do not seem to help, maybe because they are one year old at best. Therefor, I want to ask for recent advice.

**What steps do I need to take to transition a NodeJS project to Typescript?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1.Add typings to your devDependencies in package.json

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "typings": "latest"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "typings install --save"
  }
}
```

2.Add typings.json (alongside your package.json), note `postinstall` action in the package.json above - this will install typescript definitions upon each `npm install`

```
{
  "globalDependencies": {
    "node": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/node/node.d.ts"
  }
}
```

3.Add tsconfig.json

```
{ 
     "compilerOptions": { 
         "emitDecoratorMetadata": true, 
         "experimentalDecorators": true,
         "moduleResolution": "node",
         "module": "commonjs", 
         "target": "es6",
         "sourceMap": true,
         "outDir": "dist",
         "declaration": true,
         "allowJs": true,
         "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
     },
     "exclude": [
         "node_modules",
         "dist",
         ".vscode",
         "docs"
     ]
}
```

Note that `allowJs' option will help you to keep some javascript files unconverted if necessary.

4. Make transpiling of ts files part of your build process

This should get you going. After that step by step convert javascript to typescript in order to leverage its benefits.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for these detailed steps, it has been hard to know which config options to choose. However, I did try setting allowJs to true to do it incrementally (and add a build directory where the output should go), but then, the ts compiler complained that it cannot compile because it would overwrite the files in the build directory. But I did add the build directory to the excludes, just like node_modules, so I did not know what to do and just changed all files to .ts. Did I miss something there?

Comment: You did not forget to specify `outDir` in tsconfig? Also this might be connected with how your build is setup, are you using gulp/grunt or compiling directly via tsc. I have used both and both work just fine with `allowJs` option. I would suggest you to try and reduce your project to minimum in order to clearly see where the problem will disappear.

Comment: I did eventually get it to work today morning, by specifying *both* "exclude" (build, node_modules) and "include" (src, where I moved my code files)(and yes, outDir="build"). This surprised me a lot, but without it (ie. with only "exclude" or "include" I was getting those errors and tsc was setting up the file structure inside build in a very weird way.

Comment: Also, with your specific `tsconfig.json` I get the error `TS5053: Option 'allowJs' cannot be specified with option 'declaration'.`

Comment: Quite strange, I do use this two options together without any issues. Although you are correct and there is open issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7546. Thanks for the info though.

Comment: @Ludwik allowJs with declaration error in VScode is fixed in v1.3.2 or probably earlier

Comment: This answer seems outdated. Typings is officially deprecated: https://github.com/typings/typings

Answer (score 5):

## Migrating Js to TS

You create a `tsconfig.json` with `allowJs` set to true. This allows you to use the `.js` as it is!. Next you start changing the file extension from `.ts` to `.js` one by one, declaring what you find missing as you go along.

I did a video about this about a week ago https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gmKXXI_ck7w

## More :

> maybe because they are one year old at best.

I keep this up to date : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/migrating.html

Of course if you read it as a book I assume you already have seen the nodejs quickstart : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/quick/nodejs.html

Comment: Thank you for maintaining that guide. I did try setting `allowJs` to true to do it incrementally (and add a build directory where the output should go), but then, the ts compiler complained that it cannot compile because it would overwrite the files in the build directory. But I did add the build directory to the excludes, just like `node_modules`, so I did not know what to do and just changed all files to `.ts`. Did I miss something there?

Comment: Please also use `outDir`. This is shown in the video as well :)

Comment: I did use it then, but I recently got it working by adding both "include" and "exclude" (and outDir is still there). Weird that I had to use both, but oh well

Answer (score 4):

There also official documentation on how to do this

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/migrating-from-javascript.html